# Python Encoding error when readin .sav SPSS file

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, spss

I am working with sav files using https://pythonhosted.org/savReaderWriter/_modules/savReaderWriter/savHeaderReader.html. I have to do this task on Python:

The name of the variable and value labels should be `var_labels1` and `value_labels1` for `rec1`, `var_labels2` and `value_labels2` for `rec2`, and `var_labels3` and `value_labels3` for `rec3`.

I tried to run this code:

```
with sav.SavHeaderReader( r"...\Nueva carpeta\REC0111.sav") as header:
    metadata = header.all()
    var_labels1 = metadata.varLabels  
    value_labels1 = metadata.valueLabels
```

Also this one

```
with sav.SavHeaderReader( r"...\Nueva carpeta\REC0111.sav", ioUtf8=True) as header:
    metadata = header.all()
    var_labels1 = metadata.varLabels  
    value_labels1 = metadata.valueLabels
```

But I get this error:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 10: invalid continuation byte`

What can I do?

I have tried to change the SPSS encoding with Notepad++ but still get the same mistake, perhaps I haven't done it correctly although I am most certainly sure that I have.
I tried to change de SPSS encoding locally and then re-opening and resaving the file but it stil didn't work